# How to add a Repository

Tags: drivers, samsung

When trying to add a repository/PPA, I'm getting the error

> The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/langdalepl/gvfs-mtp/ubuntu bionic Release does not have a Release file.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 2):

This PPA hasn't been updated since the `raring` release (there's no `bionic` release), and hasn't been updated since 2013. So it's way too old to use for anything.